# .Net OutOfMemory on Server but not Desktop

Tags: .net, memory, memory-consumption

Is it possible that the .Net framework behaves differently when it comes to garbage collection / memory limitations on server environments? I am running explicitly x86 compiled apps on a 64bit server machine with 32gbs of physical ram and I am running out of memory (SystemOutOfMemoryException) even though nothing but that particular app is running and the server/all other apps utilize 520mb total.. but I cannot reproduce that behaviour on my own (client win7) machine.

Now I know that the app -is- memory intensive, but why is it causing problems on the server and not on the client?

Comment: Yes, if using more than about 1.5 GB, your app must be a 64-bit build to be safe against OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: Server is Win2k3, client/dev machine is x86. 64bit is not an option unfortunately atm due to the limitations mentioned below.

Answer (score 2):

**The** `OutOfMemoryException` **in .NET rarely (if ever) means that the machine is *literally* out of memory.**  `OutOfSomeNecessaryCriticalResource` would have been a less-misleading name.

The `OutOfMemoryException` really just means that whatever is going wrong, the programmer chose to throw that particular exception in that particular situation.  For example, simply calling `Image.FromFile(...)` on a corrupted JPEG (or any file format that .Net can't open) will result in an `OutOfMemoryException`, not because .NET runs out of memory, but because that's the documented type of exception thrown for an invalid file (do not ask me why, as I don't know).

To debug your particular problem, you need to find out what is throwing the `OutOfMemoryException` (and where and when).  An `OutOfMemoryException` by itself means absolutely nothing.

Comment: But most of the time an `OutOfMemoryException` indicates that a memory allocation failed. This does not mean - as you mentioned - that the machine is out of physical memory - but that there is not enough contiguous memory space available in the virtual address space of the process to satisfy the demand.

Comment: @0xA3: as I said in my answer, all you can be sure of with an `OutOfMemoryException` is that that's the type of exception that was thrown. Personally, I have *never* encountered this exception in a .NET application as a result of my program's trying to use more memory than permitted to my process, even in .NET CF where your process is limited to 32MB.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, on a Windows server you'll be using a different kind of garbage collector.  It is tuned more to the needs of a server style application, it collects garbage less aggressively.  You can change this behavior with an app.config file, using the [`<gcServer>` element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229357.aspx).

That isn't very likely to be the real problem btw, I'd guess that your app sees a more realistic pattern of usage.  Intentionally forcing x86 mode when you've got a nice 64-bit server is something you'd want to avoid, if you can.

Comment: I'd love to -not- enfore x86 and use 'any cpu'/64bit, but unfortunately the app has to use x86 due to some legacy api's/.dlls that do not work when the parent process is a 64bit one. It's using a rather odd .net > com > java > corba path and when I use 64bit I get a BadImageFormatException once that 3rd party .net dll is being loaded.